# Counting values from excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, if-statement

I need to count the accuraces of specific values in an excel sheet within a certain period. Now i have this part:

```
string sub = range.Cells[rCnt, 7].Value.ToString();

   char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', '/', '.', ':', '\t' };
   string date = range.Cells[rCnt, 4].Value.ToString();
   string[] d = date.Split(delimiterChars);

   if (d[0] == "1" && d[2] == "2012" || d[0] == "2" && d[2] == "2012" || d[0] == "3" && d[2] == "2012")
   {
        if (sub == "AM") { AM[0]++; }
   }
```

i want to make it so that if the date is january februari or march in 2012 and the value is `"AM"`
the first item in the list `AM` will add 1.

the format of the time is`" M/D/Y H:M:S"`
there are about 300 items in the sheet who have that value within those months but it gives back about 1000

could it be something with

```
List<int> AM = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 16).ToList();
```

because thats the only other thing in the code that changes the values in the list

Comment: What can suggest you is ti simplify your worksheet (e.g. take part of it) and debug your code manually to check your if statement.

Comment: Haha sorry guys hadnt to do anything with this, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `DateTime` to parse the values:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date.Trim(), "M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if((dateTime.Month == 1 || dateTime.Month == 2 || dateTime.Month == 3) && dateTime.Year == 2012)
        {
            if (sub == "AM") 
            { 
               AM[0]++; 
            }
        }
```

Tested for a date in this format: "1/1/2012 20:00:00" and it worked.

Comment: It amazes me the lengths people will go to come up with terrible solutions to problems that are already solved.